# Is CFA appropriate for test retest reliability?

Tags: factor-analysis, reliability, measurement-error, measurement, confirmatory-factor

I know CFA is often used when there is a latent variable that has measurement error that can attenuate correlations. However, does it make sense to make this same adjustment for measurement error when doing a test-retest correlation? For example, maybe there isn't a strong correlation between a measure administered at two time points but there is a correlation between the true scores (e.g., accounting for measurement error)?

Comment: Just for clarification, does CFA mean confirmatory factor analysis?

Comment: Yes, in this context, CFA is referring to confirmatory factor analysis.

Answer (score 3):

To piggy-back on Jeremy Miles's answer (his description is good, you should choose it as the correct answer--mine is just supplemental)...

If you aren't familiar with longitudinal SEM (of which this test-retest reliability model is a very simple case), I'd encourage you to check out Little's (2013) book on the topic--very helpful for understanding the important basics of SEM, and how things change when moving to modelling longitudinal processes--as Jeremy's answer attests to, keeping track of how to model "unique" ("error", or "residual") variances becomes very important.

Anyways, if you don't have much experience with SEM (longitudinal or otherwise), here is some example code of how you would fit the model that Jeremy has described, using the `lavaan` package for `R`. In this example, we're pretending that you are looking at test-retest reliability of one latent variable over two time-points, with 3 indicators of the latent variable:

```
#Simulate data of latent variable  with 3 indicators (X1-X3) that are measured at two time points (.1 and .2)
set.seed(1234)
X1.1 = rnorm(100)
X2.1 = 0.7*X + rnorm(100)
X3.1 = 0.7*X + rnorm(100)
X1.2 = 0.7*X + rnorm(100)
X2.2 = 0.7*X4 + rnorm(100)
X3.2 = 0.7*X4 + rnorm(100)
Data <- data.frame(X1.1 = X1.1, X2.1 = X2.1, X3.1 = X3.1, X1.2 = X1.2, X2.2 = X2.2, X3.2 = X3.2)

#Install and call lavaan package for SEM
install.packages("lavaan")
library(lavaan)

#Specify test-restest model
model='
#X1.1-X3.1 load onto latent variable at time 1
LV1 =~ X1.1 + X2.1 + X3.1

#X1.2-X3.2 load onto latent variable at time 2
LV2 =~ X1.2 + X2.2 + X3.2

#Estimate correlation between LV1 and LV2
LV1 ~~ LV2

#Estimate the residual covariances between the same indicators at different time points
X1.1 ~~ X1.2
X2.1 ~~ X2.2
X3.1 ~~ X3.2
'

#Fit model to data, using fixed-factor method of identification and scale-setting
testretest = cfa(model, data=Data, std.lv = TRUE)

#Request summary output
summary(testretest)
```

Which would give you the following output...

```
lavaan (0.5-18) converged normally after  30 iterations

  Number of observations                           100

  Estimator                                         ML
  Minimum Function Test Statistic                6.226
  Degrees of freedom                                 5
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.285

Parameter estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Standard Errors                             Standard

                   Estimate  Std.err  Z-value  P(>|z|)
Latent variables:
  LV1 =~
    X1.1              0.111    0.138    0.803    0.422
    X2.1              0.753    0.170    4.425    0.000
    X3.1              0.553    0.141    3.933    0.000
  LV2 =~
    X1.2              1.522    0.260    5.860    0.000
    X2.2              0.451    0.137    3.292    0.001
    X3.2              0.532    0.143    3.725    0.000

Covariances:
  LV1 ~~
    LV2               0.468    0.139    3.376    0.001
  X1.1 ~~
    X1.2              0.001    0.087    0.009    0.993
  X2.1 ~~
    X2.2             -0.007    0.135   -0.050    0.960
  X3.1 ~~
    X3.2             -0.151    0.115   -1.313    0.189

Variances:
    X1.1              0.986    0.141
    X2.1              0.863    0.233
    X3.1              0.926    0.169
    X1.2             -0.895    0.786
    X2.2              1.405    0.206
    X3.2              1.206    0.192
    LV1               1.000
    LV2               1.000
```

Within all of that output, your test-retest reliability in this example would be captured by the covariance between LV1 ~~ LV2 (*r* = .47, *p* = .01). The covariances between each indicator at both time points (e.g., X1.1 ~~ X1.2), alternatively, ensure that the dependency between related observed variables is adequately captured.

Comment: FYI: running this example will result in some cranky warning messages, on account of the negative estimated variance of X1.2.

Comment: BTW, I think there is an error in the code above. "X" doesn't seem to be defined in the R script.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is appropriate, and it is a type of quasi-simplex model.

There are two effects that you take into account. The correlation between the true scores is assess by the correlation between the latent variables, but you also correlate the unique (error) variances of the measured variables - to ensure that you are only estimating the correlation of the true scores and have removed the correlation in the errors.